# Curves and line consisted figure

Tags: graphics

Any advice will be appreciable for the attached figure [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[-latex,thick] (0,0) -- (11,0) node[below]{$x$};
\draw[-latex,thick] (0,0) -- (0,7) node[left]{$y$};
\draw[red,thick,dashed] (2,0) -- (2,5);
\draw[red,thick,dashed] (7,0) -- (7,5);
\draw[thick] (0.5,4) to [out=-100,in=150]
node[midway,below left,red!50!black]{comment 2} (2,1) 
node[below left]{comment 3} to node[pos=0.3,below=0.2cm,red!50!black]{comment 3} 
node[midway,above=1cm]{comment 1}(7,1) to[out=0,in=-90] 
node[pos=0.3,below right]{comment 5} node[pos=0.55,below right,red!50!black]{comment 6}
(10,5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]